# $L^p$ space and Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let be $q>p$ then $L^q(\Omega)\subset L^p(\Omega)$. I will be able to say that all $f \in L^q$, such that $q>1$, have a Fourier Transform?.

pdta:I asking this because I am read that exist Fourier transform only when $f \in L^1$ but $L^q \subset L^p$.

Comment: On which space are you working? With which measure?

Comment: In the Lebesgue space

Comment: And what is $\Omega$?

Comment: The inclusion between $L^p$ spaces is only valid for $\Omega$ with finite measure (in this case: the larger the exponent, the smaller the space). I think this is what @Davide Giraudo is after...

Comment: $\Omega$ is bounded

Comment: What is the definition of the Fourier transform? From this, we can find a sufficient condition for the itengral defining it exists.

Comment: I suggest you put the condition: $\Omega$ is bounded into the post.

Answer (score 1):

Given a Banach space with a multiplication (usually convolution in $L^p$-spaces) such that 
$$\|x\cdot y\|\leq C \|x\|\cdot \|y\|$$
we do have a Gelfand transform which on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ coincides with the Fourier transform or in the case of $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ the Fourier coefficients (here $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\sim(-\pi,\pi]$ is the circle group).

That $\Omega$ is bounded is not really sufficient in order to have a *worthy* Fourier transform.
Surely, for bounded $\Omega$ and $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ we may define $$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_\Omega f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx$$
Now, by defining $f=0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\Omega$ we extend $f$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, and then we may consider a translate of $f$, i.e.
$f_a(x)=f(x-a)$, for which we have
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f_a(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x-a)e^{-ix\xi}dx=\\\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-i(x+a)\xi}dx=e^{-ia\xi}\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx=e^{-ia\xi}\hat{f}(\xi)$$
This is a problem because if $f$ is nice enough, we would have an inverse Fourier transform and the translate must then belong to $L^p(\Omega)$ - but that is not the case unless we have some additional algebraic structure on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Fourier transform exists not only when $f \in L^1$;  the Fourier transform can also be defined in the space of $L^2$ and some other spaces, like spaces of generalized functions corresponding to tempered distributions.

Second, $L^q(\Omega)$ is not necessary a subspace of  $L^p(\Omega)$ if $\Omega$ is unbounded.